# Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?

Tags: python, python-internals

Is there a way to see how built in functions work in python? I don't mean just how to use them, but also how were they built, what is the code behind ***sorted*** or ***enumerate*** etc...?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Since Python is open source you can read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython).

To find out what file a particular module or function is implemented in you can usually print the `__file__` attribute. Alternatively, you may use the `inspect` module, see the section [Retrieving Source Code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) in the documentation of `inspect`.

For built-in classes and methods this is not so straightforward since `inspect.getfile` and `inspect.getsource` will return a type error stating that the object is built-in. However, many of the built-in types can be found in the [`Objects` sub-directory of the Python source trunk](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/). For example, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/enumobject.c) for the implementation of the enumerate class or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) for the implementation of the `list` type.

Comment: Can you give an example with `enumerate`?

Comment: following the OP, how about the source code for "sorted"? of course, inspect.getsourcefile(sorted) doesn't work.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl the source code for `sorted()` is in [/Python/bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d246a6766b9d8cc625112906299c4cb019944300/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2236-L2237) although it just calls `list.sort()` so the real source is in [/Objects/listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/listobject.c#L2151-L2152)

Comment: would have been helpful if you had given an example of how to use  ```__file__```

Comment: As a note to self, and for the future googlers: the `open()` functions is defined in `Modules/_io/_iomodule.c` in Python 3 (and not among the other builtins).

Comment: Where can I find the `nt` module?  (Example reference:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/abde52cd8e31830bfc06c5803221faae6172104a/Lib/ntpath.py#L518 )

Comment: I tried input.__file__ but it says 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '_ _ file _ _'. :-\

Answer (score 49):

Here is a cookbook answer to supplement [@Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608609/3357935), CPython has moved to GitHub and the Mercurial repository will no longer be updated:

1. Install Git if necessary.
2. `git clone https://github.com/python/cpython.git`
3. Code will checkout to a subdirectory called `cpython` -> `cd cpython`
4. Let's say we are looking for the definition of `print()`...
5. `egrep --color=always -R 'print' | less -R`
6. Aha!  See `Python/bltinmodule.c` -> `builtin_print()`

Enjoy.

Comment: `bltinmodule`. Arrrrrrrrrgh. Why did they have to spell it so badly? I tried a quick filesystem search for `builtin` and came up with nothing!

Answer (score 48):

[image]

I had to dig a little to find the source of the following `Built-in Functions` as the search would yield thousands of results. (Good luck searching for any of those to find where it's source is)

Anyway, all those functions are defined in `bltinmodule.c` Functions start with `builtin_{functionname}`

> Built-in Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c
>
> For Built-in Types:
> https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects

Comment: A list is an object/type, not a builtin function. You can find the implementation details for that in `listobject.c` https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects

Comment: `dir` is not implemented in C so it's not in that file.

Comment: Looking for the implementation of [builtin `pow` in bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1927), I only find an unhelpful `static PyObject * builtin_pow_impl(PyObject *module, PyObject *base, PyObject *exp, PyObject *mod) { return PyNumber_Power(base, exp, mod); }`. Is there an easy way to find where the actual algorithm implementation is hidden?

Answer (score 26):

The [iPython](http://ipython.org/) shell makes this easy: `function?` will give you the documentation. `function??` shows also the code. BUT this only works for pure python functions.

Then you can always [download](http://python.org/download/source/) the source code for the (c)Python.

If you're interested in pythonic implementations of core functionality have a look at [PyPy](http://pypy.org) source.

Comment: PyPy uses RPython for most built-in stuff, which can be nearly as low-level as C to almost as high-level as Python. Usually it's in between. In either case it's statically typed, so it isn't really Python.

Comment: See an early project for viewing source code of a builtin function: https://github.com/punchagan/cinspect

Answer (score 16):

2 methods,

1. You can check usage about snippet using `help()`
2. you can check hidden code for those modules using `inspect`

**1) inspect:**

use **inpsect** module to explore code you want... 
**NOTE:** you can able to explore code only for modules (aka) packages you have imported

for eg:

```
  >>> import randint  
  >>> from inspect import getsource
  >>> getsource(randint) # here i am going to explore code for package called `randint`
```

**2) help():**

you can simply use `help()` command to get help about builtin functions as well its code.

for eg:
  if you want to see the code for str() , simply  type - `help(str)`

it will return like this,

```
>>> help(str)
Help on class str in module __builtin__:

class str(basestring)
 |  str(object='') -> string
 |
 |  Return a nice string representation of the object.
 |  If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      str
 |      basestring
 |      object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
 |
 |  __contains__(...)
 |      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
 |
 |  __eq__(...)
 |      x.__eq__(y) <==> x==y
 |
 |  __format__(...)
 |      S.__format__(format_spec) -> string
 |
 |      Return a formatted version of S as described by format_spec.
 |
 |  __ge__(...)
 |      x.__ge__(y) <==> x>=y
 |
 |  __getattribute__(...)
-- More  --
```

Comment: The OP specifically wants to look at the code, help gives only documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Let's go straight to your question.

**Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?**

The source code is located at `cpython/Python/bltinmodule.c`

To find the source code in the GitHub repository go [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c). You can see that all in-built functions start with `builtin_<name_of_function>`, for instance, `sorted()` is implemented in `builtin_sorted`.

For your pleasure I'll post the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d246a6766b9d8cc625112906299c4cb019944300/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2237) of `sorted()`:

```
builtin_sorted(PyObject *self, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs, PyObject *kwnames)
{
    PyObject *newlist, *v, *seq, *callable;

    /* Keyword arguments are passed through list.sort() which will check
       them. */
    if (!_PyArg_UnpackStack(args, nargs, "sorted", 1, 1, &seq))
        return NULL;

    newlist = PySequence_List(seq);
    if (newlist == NULL)
        return NULL;

    callable = _PyObject_GetAttrId(newlist, &PyId_sort);
    if (callable == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(newlist);
        return NULL;
    }

    assert(nargs >= 1);
    v = _PyObject_FastCallKeywords(callable, args + 1, nargs - 1, kwnames);
    Py_DECREF(callable);
    if (v == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(newlist);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(v);
    return newlist;
}
```

As you may have noticed, that's not Python code, but C code.

Answer (score 10):

Quite an unknown resource is the Python [Developer Guide](https://devguide.python.org/).

In a (somewhat) recent GH [issue](https://github.com/python/devguide/issues/136), a new chapter was added for to address the question you're asking: [CPython Source Code Layout](https://devguide.python.org/exploring/). If something should change, that resource will also get updated.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @Jim, the file organization is described [here](https://devguide.python.org/exploring/). Reproduced for ease of discovery:

> For Python modules, the typical layout is:
>
> ```
> Lib/<module>.py
> Modules/_<module>.c (if there’s also a C accelerator module)
> Lib/test/test_<module>.py
> Doc/library/<module>.rst
> ```
>
> For extension-only modules, the typical layout is:
>
> ```
> Modules/<module>module.c
> Lib/test/test_<module>.py
> Doc/library/<module>.rst
> ```
>
> For builtin types, the typical layout is:
>
> ```
> Objects/<builtin>object.c
> Lib/test/test_<builtin>.py
> Doc/library/stdtypes.rst
> ```
>
> For builtin functions, the typical layout is:
>
> ```
> Python/bltinmodule.c
> Lib/test/test_builtin.py
> Doc/library/functions.rst
> ```
>
> Some exceptions:
>
> ```
> builtin type int is at Objects/longobject.c
> builtin type str is at Objects/unicodeobject.c
> builtin module sys is at Python/sysmodule.c
> builtin module marshal is at Python/marshal.c
> Windows-only module winreg is at PC/winreg.c
> ```