# How to check source code of a python method?

Tags: python, methods

To be short, suppose I have a string `'next'`,

```
next = "123rpq"
```

and I can apply a `str` method `.isdigit()` to `'next'`. So my question is how to check the implementation of this method. Hence is there a thing like `inspect.getsource(somefunction)` to get the source code of a 'method'?

UPDATE: see comment about variable name `'next'` below.

Comment: Please don't call your variable 'next' because it shadows the builtin `next`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For modules, classes, functions and a few other objects you can use `inspect.getfile` or `inspect.getsourcefile`. However, for builtin objects and methods this will result in a `TypeError`. As metioned by C0deH4cker, builtin objects and methods are implemented in C, so you will have to browse the C source code. `isdigit` is a method of the builtin string object, which is implemented in the file [`unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab0e60101637b7cf47f3cc95813996791e7118c4/Objects/unicodeobject.c) in the `Objects` directory of the Python source code. This `isdigit` method is implemented [from line 11,416](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab0e60101637b7cf47f3cc95813996791e7118c4/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11416-L11451) of this file. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608609/623518) to a similar but more general question.

Answer (score 8):

The `isdigit()` method you are talking about is a builtin method of a builtin datatype. Meaning, the source of this method is written in C, not Python. If you really wish to see the source code of it, then I suggest you go to http://python.org and download the source code of Python.

Comment: We use PyCharm develop python project, and run it, does there have the python source code in our machine? otherwise how can python project run on our machines?

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing `method.__doc__` for the documentation on that particular method. If you are just curious, you could check your PYTHONPATH to see where your modules are imported from, and see if you find the .py file from that module

Comment: it's better to use `help(str.isdigit)`

Comment: @Pablo, thanks. could you give me the example using the case in my question; how to print the source code for `next.isdigit()`?

Comment: as @AshwiniChaudhary said, you could write help(str.isdigit) or str.isdigit.__doc__

Answer (score 0):

I checked cpython source code, isdigit is already a c stdlib function. This explains it satisfactorily
https://www.quora.com/How-does-isdigit-in-Python-work
what you can do is download python source code and c stdlib header files and write a script (either bash or py) to search function (whatever type it is) and isdigit (whatever you search) in same line or close proximity.

btw ,I wonder what would happen if we compile things part by part and associate code with aasembly. Would AI be able to shorten or expand our codes via comparing assemblies in a markov chain matter. AI assisted coding possible ?

Answer (score -1):

While I'd generally agree that `inspect` is a good answer, it falls flat when your class (and thus the class method) was defined in the interpreter.

If you use `dill.source.getsource` from [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill), you can get the source of functions and lambdas, even if they are defined interactively.
It also can get the code for from bound or unbound class methods and functions defined in curries... however, you might not be able to compile that code without the enclosing object's code.

```
>>> from dill.source import getsource
>>> 
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> squared = lambda x:x**2
>>> 
>>> print getsource(add)
def add(x,y):
  return x+y

>>> print getsource(squared)
squared = lambda x:x**2

>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self, x):
...     return x*x+x
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> 
>>> print getsource(f.bar)
def bar(self, x):
    return x*x+x

>>>
```

For `builtin` functions or methods, `dill.source` will not work… HOWEVER…

You still may not have to resort to using your favorite editor to open the file with the source code in it (as suggested in other answers).  There is a new package called [`cinspect`](https://github.com/punchagan/cinspect) that purports to be able to view source for `builtins`.

Comment: @user32882: Please open a GitHub issue for `dill` with a demonstration of how it doesn't work for you.  I have tested the above code in python 3.x, where x <= 2, and it works for at least the latest version `dill`.  If you are experiencing failures, then open a Github issue and I'll help you out.

Comment: Done. Please take a look at https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/359. Thanks!