# What is time complexity str.isdigit() in Python?

Tags: python

If I would like to know other built-in function's time complexity, what are the ways to figure it out except for looking for [cheatsheet](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: Think about what is the input. For a string - how would you check if it's a digit without looking at all N characters? And there's no reason to look at any more than once

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253955/how-to-check-source-code-of-a-python-method can tell you where to find the source code, and the source code for many python builtins lives there.  As for `isdigit` specifically, you will find that it uses the `isdigit` function from the C standard library.  So finding the time complexity of that function would answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what you're actually trying to do, verifying that the string is a digit. The only way to be 100% sure about that is by making sure every character in the string is a digit, therefore it needs to evaluate *every* character.

Therefore it has a linear time complexity, O(n), where n is the length of the string