# Viewing Python 2.6 source code

Tags: python

I wanted to know how the `max()` builtin function works. So I tried to read the source code at `svn.python.org`, but I couldn't find the `__builtin__` module. It should be in `__builtin__.py`, right?

Can somebody tell me where to find the source code for this module? Is this available in `ubuntu linux` (which has the 2.6 version)?

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd853311ffe0/Objects

Comment: Python development moved from `svn` to `hg` a couple of years ago.  The Python source repos at `svn.python.org` are out-of-date.  Use `hg.python.org` as noted above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__builtin__` as its name implies, refers to the special module containing functions and classes built in to the language itself.  The [implementation of these functions](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c) is in C, not Python.  (Specifically, in the `bltinmodule.c` source file.)

Comment: See the "builtin_max" function

Comment: Here's the link to [`builtin_max`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9910fd022fc/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1439) in the [2.6.8 hg repo](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9910fd022fc). `min_max` starts at line 1336.