# How do I view the code for built-in functions using the Python IDLE?

Tags: python, directory, built-in

I'm trying to look at the source code of the `pow()` function, and would like to get to know my way around the Python34 directory. I've looked at various libraries in the `Lib` directory such as `fractions.py`, and `base64.py`, but I can't seem to find the `.py` file where built-in functions are stored. Where should I look?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Comment: You are probably looking for `.c` file, not `.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Builtins and functions from the standard library are not always implemented in Python. In CPython (the reference Python implementation), they're often written in C

The method you are looking for is defined in the following files (depending on the type you're interested in):

- Float: [`Objects/floatobject.c:643`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/230a27866930de1587cdc1bf760301eb533856fb/Objects/floatobject.c#L643-L763)
- Long: [`Objects/longobject.c:3809`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/230a27866930de1587cdc1bf760301eb533856fb/Objects/longobject.c#L3809-L3997)
- ...

You can actually grep the `Objects` directory in the CPython source tree for `/*nb_power*/` to find more. Try [this search query on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?l=c&q=nb_power&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: Also see `PyNumber_Power` in http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c and `ternary_op` in http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/r23a1-branch/Objects/abstract.c

Answer (score 0):

Functions which `repr` contain the wording "built-in" are not actually defined in Python code, in cPython - they are ratehr written in C, and amde available as binary modules.

For example, when you get the repr of "pow" you get:

```
>>> repr(pow)
'<built-in function pow>'
```

In contrast with a Python defined function:

```
>>> import glob
>>> repr (glob.glob)
'<function glob at 0x7efefe69aa70>'
```

So, you can search for the C source code of functions marked as "built-in" in the source code for Python itself, if you download it from Python.org (or fetch it with mercurial).

If you want a pure Python implementation of any function in the satandard lib, that should be included with the pypy distribution - just fetch it from:

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy  and you should see pure Python implementation of all functions that in cPython are implemented in C for performance or historic reasons.