# What is the source code of __hash__() and __eq__() of object in Python?

Tags: python, python-internals

`object` is a base for all new style classes. Where can I find the source code of `object`? I'd like to have a look how the function `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` are defined.

Refer to this answer ([Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)), I search the object definition in [cpython](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/).

There is not `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` definiton in https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c.

Comment: Not sure about equality but for hashing you might want to look [at this file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pyhash.c)

Comment: @Waylan: Despite what it might look like, those functions aren't actually the `object.__eq__` or `object.__hash__` implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementations for `__hash__` and `__eq__` are inherited from the base `object` type. You can find its type definition in [`typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/374f501f4567/Objects/typeobject.c#l4416):

```c
PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    …
    (hashfunc)_Py_HashPointer,                  /* tp_hash */
    …
    object_richcompare,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    …
};
```

For the hash function (`tp_hash`), the default hash function for references is used, `_Py_HashPointer`. It is defined in [`pyhash.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/374f501f4567/Python/pyhash.c#l131):

```c
Py_hash_t
_Py_HashPointer(void *p)
{
    Py_hash_t x;
    size_t y = (size_t)p;
    /* bottom 3 or 4 bits are likely to be 0; rotate y by 4 to avoid
       excessive hash collisions for dicts and sets */
    y = (y >> 4) | (y << (8 * SIZEOF_VOID_P - 4));
    x = (Py_hash_t)y;
    if (x == -1)
        x = -2;
    return x;
}
```

This basically uses the pointer address as a base for the hash.

When `__eq__` is called, what Python does under the hood is perform a rich comparison (`tp_richcompare`). This includes both equality and non-equality check as well as comparisons like greater or lower than. The default implementation is using [`object_richcompare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/374f501f4567/Objects/typeobject.c#l3507) which requires a reference equality:

```c
static PyObject *
object_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    PyObject *res;

    switch (op) {

    case Py_EQ:
        /* Return NotImplemented instead of False, so if two
           objects are compared, both get a chance at the
           comparison.  See issue #1393. */
        res = (self == other) ? Py_True : Py_NotImplemented;
        Py_INCREF(res);
        break;

    …

    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `object` implementation is actually in `Objects/typeobject.c`, for some reason. Looking in that file, you can see from the [`PyBaseObject_Type` definition](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/typeobject.c#l4428):

```
PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    ...
    (hashfunc)_Py_HashPointer,                  /* tp_hash */
    ...
    object_richcompare,                         /* tp_richcompare */
```

that `object.__eq__` is implemented in [`object_richcompare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/typeobject.c#l3499), and `object.__hash__` is implemented in [`_Py_HashPointer`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/pyhash.c#l131) from `Python/pyhash.c`.

In [Python 2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l3596):

```
PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    ...
    0,                                          /* tp_compare */
    ...
    (hashfunc)_Py_HashPointer,                  /* tp_hash */
    ...
    0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
```

`object.__eq__` simply doesn't exist, so `==` ultimately falls back on a pointer comparison in [`default_3way_compare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l762). `_Py_HashPointer` still exists, but it's in [`Objects/object.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l762)