# How can I check how standard classes (e.g. socket) implement their rich comparisons (e.g. `__eq__`) in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, comparison

How can I check how standard classes (e.g. socket) implement their rich comparisons (e.g. `__eq__`) in Python3?

I'm learning Python and have implemented a web server in the language.

I'm not sure whether it's safe to compare sockets by `==` to determine if the listening server socket `s` is part of the read list returned by `select.select()`.

I've consulted the documentation for sockets (see below), but a search for "equal" doesn't show anything.

Is there a general rule that rich comparisons are left unimplemented unless otherwise stated? If so, how is comparison performed?

References:

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**cmp**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Comment: `__cmp__` doesn't exist in Python 3, which version are you actually using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm using Python2/3. I maybe restate my question to "how to determine the implementation of equality for Python classes ".

Comment: That's almost deliberately not an answer. Do you mean you're writing code that supports both 2 *and* 3 (and at [this point](https://pythonclock.org/), frankly, *why*)? If you want to restate your question, [edit] it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I've edited thanks. Because some code is still Python2 and I need to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask Python what `__eq__` is, e. g.:

```
>>> socket.socket.__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
```

From this, I'd conclude that the `socket` module doesn't  implement its own rich comparison for a `socket` object, but rather uses the general method for `object` objects.

Perhaps you might also want to read about [Python method-wrapper type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401935/python-method-wrapper-type)

> By default,  `eq` compares objects by their address (`id()`), right? How do I know this C-implemented function does that?

To know for sure, you can look at the source; see [What is the source code of **hash**() and **eq**() of object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709339/what-is-the-source-code-of-hash-and-eq-of-object-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. `<slot wrapper>` is a C-implemented function. By default,  `__eq__` compares objects by their address (`id()`), right? How do I know this C-implemented function does that?

Comment: I hope the amendment above answers that question.