# How can I see Python's __builtins__ source code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in, inspect

Can I get python to print the source code for `__builtins__` directly?

OR (more preferably):

What is the pathname of the source code for `__builtins__`?

---

I at least know the following things:

- `__builtins__` is a module, by typing `type(__builtins__)`.
- I have tried the best-answer-suggestions to a more general case of this SO question: ["Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions). But no luck:

  - `print inspect.getdoc(__builtins__)` just gives me a description.
  - `inspect.getfile(__builtins__)` just gives me an error: `TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in module`
  - https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/# does not seem to contain an entry for `__builtins__`. I've tried "site:" search and browsed several of the directories but gave up after a few.

Comment: @MooingRawr I have tried the answers in that original post

Comment: should have mention that... then ....

Comment: @MooingRawr, cheers, my bad will edit

Comment: Note: the `__builtins__` name is an implementation detail, and `__builtins__` does not behave as consistently as you might expect. For example, it's not always a module! If you want to access the module where built-in names are defined, you should `import __builtin__` (no s), or `import builtins` (no underscores) on Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__builtin__` module is implemented in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c), a rather unusual location for a rather unusual module.

Comment: Cheers, how did you know this? or how did you work it out?

Comment: @Oracle: I've just spent a lot of time looking through the Python source code, so I'm familiar with where a lot of things are.

Comment: Respect. At least I know there isn't some tool I'm missing out on (maybe).

Answer (score -2):

I can't try it right now, but python default ide is able to open core modules easily (I tried with math and some more)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html

On menus. Open module.

Comment: Could you give a example of what you mean?

Comment: I don't understand: "I can try it right now" (try what?), "but" (are you sure you mean but?), "open core modules easily" (yes I bet it can, but how? what line of code?)

Comment: I'm writing on the phone, and sadly I can't use idle here :) I edited to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Ah IDLE, well I probably have IDLE installed (I use sublime) but it would really be nice to do this without a GUI and I'm guessing it would just give me a huge list to choose from. Because my sys.path is quite huge.

Comment: Does this display the real source code? I've seen [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384206/why-some-python-build-in-functions-only-have-pass) in PyCharm that just fabricates code that kind of looks like it could have been the source code.

Comment: Now I have doubts, but probably you are right, idle shouldn't handle c file's