# Where are the python Built-in functions stored?

Tags: python

Like we have python modules in the standard library from which we can import methods and use them, is there also a module where all the built-in functions are defined?
If yes, how can I view that module?

Comment: Did you try googling [Python built-in function module](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+built-in+function+module)?

Comment: I wanted to know from where I could view the contents of 'builtins' module...i.e. the exact code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851872/how-can-i-see-pythons-builtins-source-code/40851954#40851954

Comment: thanks @user2357112

Comment: btw why are those not '.py' modules, but, C source code files?

Comment: Because they're not written in Python. They're C. Not all of the CPython implementation is written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (Python 3) or [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/__builtin__.html) (Python 2) module provides access to them.

This is even useful sometimes if you rebind the name of a builtin, eg `list = [1, 2, 3]`. You generally shouldn't do that, but if you do you can still access the builtin list constructor as `builtins.list`.

Comment: Note that `builtins` is `__builtin__` in Python 2.

Comment: Does there exists a module such as 'builtins.py' ? If yes, where is it located in the python directory?

Answer (score 0):

On python3, `import builtins` or `import __builtin__` for older versions

You can check any modules content with the `dir` function