# Pycharm: Is there a way to go to declaration of built-in data structures?

Tags: python, pycharm

I think Eclipse has this with Java std lib. I believe you can search `Object` then go view the source of the `Object` class.

I want to be able to search for and view the source of something like `list` in Python.

In Pycharm, I can go to declaration of anything such as `import os` or `c = ClassFromMyModule()`, but with a dict or list, it's not the same.

I can't go to declaration of a literal or an operator. Such as:

```
d = {}
l = ['hello', 'there']
my_str = "hello there"
a = b + c
```

Comment: Related: [Why do some built-in Python functions only have pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384206/3357935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write something like:

```
x = list()
```

and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on `list`. It will bring you to a file called `builtins.py`, but **lists and dictionaries are builtins**, these are usually **implemented by the interpreter**. So as a result these have **no Python implementation**, it will show you something like:

```
class list(object):
    """
    list() -> new empty list
    list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
    """
    def append(self, p_object): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end """
        pass

    def clear(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ L.clear() -> None -- remove all items from L """
        pass
    # ...
```

So it is actually more a "virtual" class definition that is generated based on the documentation. The `list` object is *not* implemented in Python itself: it is an object implemented in the Python interpreter. This makes sense since it is impossible to implement a list (with fast random access) without having something like a list/array.

Comment: Would it be difficult to go the implementation used by my interpreter?

Comment: @JamesT.: these are usually written in C/C++. This is for instance the `list` object: https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.6/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c

Answer (score 1):

```
import builtins
```

Go to declaration of this.