# spaCy 3.0, installed files are different from the files in github repo

Tags: spacy

I installed spaCy 3.0 on my ubuntu. I use ctrl+B to find the definition of class "sentencizer" which is in sentencizer.py file:

```
class Sentencizer(__spacy_pipeline_pipe.Pipe):
    """
    Segment the Doc into sentences using a rule-based strategy.
    
        DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer
    """
    def from_bytes(self, bytes_data, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; NOTE: unreliably restored from __doc__ 
        """
        Sentencizer.from_bytes(self, bytes_data, *, exclude=tuple())
        Load the sentencizer from a bytestring.
        
                bytes_data (bytes): The data to load.
                returns (Sentencizer): The loaded object.
        
                DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer#from_bytes
        """
        pass
...
```

Why there is no content in the functions defined in sentencizer.py. In the spaCy github repo, there is no sentencizer.py file and the class "sentencizer" is defined in [sentencizer.pyx](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/sentencizer.pyx):

```
class Sentencizer(Pipe):
    """Segment the Doc into sentences using a rule-based strategy.
    DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer
    """

    default_punct_chars = ['!', '.', '?', '։', '؟', '۔', '܀', '܁', '܂', '߹',
            '।', '॥', '၊', '။', '።', '፧', '፨', '᙮', '᜵', '᜶', '᠃', '᠉', '᥄',
            '᥅', '᪨', '᪩', '᪪', '᪫', '᭚', '᭛', '᭞', '᭟', '᰻', '᰼', '᱾', '᱿',
            '‼', '‽', '⁇', '⁈', '⁉', '⸮', '⸼', '꓿', '꘎', '꘏', '꛳', '꛷', '꡶',
            '꡷', '꣎', '꣏', '꤯', '꧈', '꧉', '꩝', '꩞', '꩟', '꫰', '꫱', '꯫', '﹒',
            '﹖', '﹗', '！', '．', '？', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
            '｡', '。']
```

Why the installed files are different from the github repo? Thanks!

Comment: When you say you use ctrl+b to find the definition, what software are you using for that? Also, what's your full spaCy version - 3.0.3 or an earlier one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing a Python library, small changes are saved in Git as they're made, but they're only released to PyPI when the maintainer intentionally makes a release. So it's normal for the files on your computer to be a little different from the files in a git repo, even if you have a very recent release.

I was really confused about the `sentencizer.py` code you posted, since there doesn't seem to have ever been a file with that name in spaCy, but it looks like that is a [magic PyCharm feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384206/why-do-some-built-in-python-functions-only-have-pass) - it's not showing you the actual source code, it's doing some sort of decompilation.

You noticed spaCy has the `sentencizer.pyx` file. That's compiled into a binary `.so` file that Python runs when you use the code. PyCharm is presumably working backwards from the `.so` file.