# how tme.time() return timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, time

```
import time
x = time.time()
print(x)
```

get the result below:
[image]

I go into the function time(),found it returns 0.0
[image]

so how time.time() return the result timestamp 1649244158.8909402?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384206/why-do-some-built-in-python-functions-only-have-pass.