# Define Function that Finds Source code of Bulit-In Function of Python

Tags: python

I'd like to construct a Function that calls the sourcecode of requested bulit-in function, e.g.

```
def recall_source_of_built_in(sum()):
    #look up the directory of where the source codes are listed in windows
    #find the function whetehr it exists
    #if exists, open/read/ and display it on my Shell
```

To build up this function, from where I have to start from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Comment: Passing `sum()` into your function like that is going to call `sum` and pass the result to the function, not the actual function.

Comment: @user3591723 now I am having a trouble to find the dir_path of where builtins are stored. How can I get there? OS: Windows 10