# Where to find python source code for built in open()

Tags: python, python-internals

I am looking for the source code for python built in function `open()`,
I've checked the bltinmodule.c but found no `open()` inside.
Does anyone know where the source of `open()` is?
Or, how to find it?
Thank you.

Comment: please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Comment: Look in `Lib/_pyio.py`.  Depending on what you want, you might also need `Objects/fileobject.c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Python on GitHub](https://github.com/python/), have a look at:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/io.py#L59
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_pyio.py#L40
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/fileutils.c#L989