# Python add two sets and delete duplicate elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to add two sets and delete duplicates

```
>>> a = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> b = set(['c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> c = a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'
>>>

Expected output:
c = set(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])
```

Comment: `union` or `update `

Comment: Sets don't have `+`, they have `|`. (Or the `union` method.)

Comment: Also, "delete duplicate elements" is misleading—sets can't have duplicate elements; there's only going to be one `'c'` in the output, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> a = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> b = set(['c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> c = a.union(b)
```

Result:

> `set(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])`

Answer (score 3):

**Use `union` method**

You want to use the `union` method of a set:

```
c = a.union(b)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sets#frozenset.union

The union method is the same as the `|` operator, so the line of code above is equivalent to

```
c = a | b
```

**Use in-place operator**

If you have no need to retain `a` or `b`, it would be better to use the `update` method, which will add the new members in place. That is,

```
a.update(b)
```

will produce the union in the existing data structure `a`. This is also performed by the equivalent code

```
a |= b
```

**Sidenote: use `set` literal**

In the code you provide, it would be faster to use the set literal notation with `{element, element, ...}`:

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

because it will execute twice as fast and not generate the unused list object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the union of both sets using the logical or operator `|`

```
a = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = set(['c', 'd', 'e'])
c = a | b

print(c)
```

> {'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c'}

If you want the set ordered and as a list

```
c = sorted(list(c))
print(c)
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Comment: The `|` operator is not the logical OR operator in this case. The operands would have to be Boolean for that operator to be applied. It is the same character, of course.

Comment: `set.union` is a distinct Python function from `bool.__or__`. They call different code, accept different arguments, and have different behavior. Only the latter, for example, uses shortcut evaluation.

Comment: You're right. Are you compiling everyone's answers into yours?

Comment: No, though I did add a section for in-place and a section advising use of the literal. I don't think anyone else had mentioned those. Is there something from someone's answer I should put in the answer I gave? And is compiling other's work frowned upon or encouraged in SO?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166651/discussion-between-bennett-brown-and-jahknows).

Comment: @BennettBrown `bool.__or__` does not short-circuit. The `or` operator is not overloadable, and the `|` operator (which i overloaded by `__or__`) is not short-circuiting.

Comment: @abarnert, Thanks, you are right! Testing it, I see that logical operator  `or` short circuits but that bitwise oeprator  `|` and equivalent `__or__` do not short circuit. Is there a way to refer to the code called by `or`?

Comment: @BennettBrown: [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) defines `or`. It doesn't explain that you can't overload it, but [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) does explain that `__or__` is for `|`. See [PEP 335](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) and the linked discussions for suggestions to change this up to 2011, when it was finally (after many years) rejected, and [PEP 532](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0532/) for a newer deferred-but-still-live proposal.

Comment: @BennettBrown If you want more detail, this could make for a good question, where an answer could go into the reasons why it isn't trivial, the history, the design reasoning involved, the idiomatic way to simulate `or` in the C API, etc. By the way, you may have guessed this, but if you need a function that does `or`, you can't use `operator.or_`, because that's `|` again, so you need something like `lambda x, y: x or y`.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks useful links!  Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions  I found this for `or`:https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/boolobject.c

Comment: @BennettBrown: That's not `or`, that's `bool.__or__`, aka `|`. Notice that it converts to the integer 0 or 1 and does a C bitwise or `|`, not a C boolean or `||` (or just calls the `nb_or` slot, which is the C API way of calling `__or__`).

Answer (score -2):

```
c = set(set(list(a) + list(b))
```

set() return `<str set>` so can't add two set together

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: What is `<str set>` supposed to mean, and why should it mean you can't add two sets together? Also, why would you convert the result to a set and then convert it to a set again?

Comment: you can try print " print type(set(['a', 'b', 'c'])) - python 2.7

Comment: Have you actually tried what you suggested? Because it gives `<type 'set'>`, not `<str set>`. And of course `set()` doesn't return the same thing as `type(set())`; the set type is a type, not a set. And meanwhile, why would the name of the type control which operators it supports? It's the dunder methods (or type slots, for builtins) that control that.