# Any built-in way to print source code for built-in functions like list() & set()?

Tags: python-3.x

Title says it all. Does python 3 contain any built-in way to print the source code for its built in functions? The `inspect` module doesn't seem to work for these.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8608587/825190

Comment: Okay so to confirm, it looks like the answer is: No?

Comment: Indeed the short answer is No. And notice that source code of built-in function in CPython is in C.