# How to get the source code for property in python

Tags: python, pandas, inspect

I want to programmatically get the source code for a given class property (e.g., `pandas.DataFrame.iloc`). I tried using `inspect.findsource()`, which works fine for classes and functions. However, it doesn't work for properties.

```py
import pandas
import inspect

type(pandas.DataFrame) # type
inspect.findsource(pandas.DataFrame)  # works ok

type(pandas.DataFrame.apply) # function
inspect.findsource(pandas.DataFrame.apply)  # works ok

type(pandas.DataFrame.iloc) # property
inspect.findsource(pandas.DataFrame.iloc) # throws exception
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got property
```

Why `inspect` cannot find source for property? How can I programmatically get the source code (or source file path) for a given property?

Comment: If I am correct  `property` is implemented in [C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3191391515824fa7f3c573d807f1034c6a28fab3/Objects/clinic/descrobject.c.h#L68). That could be the cause of this exception. `findsource` [does not work with object if it is implemented in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968628/finding-the-source-code-of-methods-implemented-in-c)

Comment: the magic `??pd.DataFrame.iloc` works pretty well in Jupyter.

Comment: If you know it’s a property, you can examine its attributes to find the underlying functions.  (There can be up to 3, each from its own file!)

Comment: @QuangHoang right! But `??pd.DataFrame.iloc` gives a popup in Jupyter. Can I redirect the content in popup to a variable?

Comment: @Ida now that's beyond my knowledge :-)