# how to know computational engine of a module in python?

Tags: python

I use the Python mesa library for agent based modeling
I wanted to know how to find out if modeling calculations are done in Python or in C language
tnx

Comment: You can find it out taking a look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how the methods of a module do their work under the hood take a direct or indirect look at the source code of the module. You can use for that purpose a file explorer, a text editor with search in files function or for indirect look for example the Python inspect module.

If the module comes as pure Python code files and you don't need to run a C(++) compiler to install it from source you have a pure Python code driven module.

Check out [Finding the source code of methods implemented in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968628/finding-the-source-code-of-methods-implemented-in-c) for some of the how-to details on this subject.