# How can get the source code of built-in class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, built-in

`property` is a class in python.

```
type(property)
<class 'type'>
callable(property)
True
```

I want to get the source code of the built-in class:

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(property)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 1024, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 817, in findsource
    file = getsourcefile(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 697, in getsourcefile
    filename = getfile(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 666, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <class 'property'> is a built-in class
```

Comment: It's implemented in C, so it doesn't have any Python source code to show.

Comment: How can get the c source code which implement property class?

Comment: The c source code which implement property class is kept as secret?

Comment: CPython is open source. I don't know of an automatic way to find the C source, but I found it by hand. The declaration is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58f5227d7cdff803609a0bda6882997b3a5ec4bf/Objects/descrobject.c#L1958-L2000

Comment: See also [Finding the source code of methods implemented in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968628/finding-the-source-code-of-methods-implemented-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because in CPython (the most popular implementation of Python, and the one that's you're using) `property` is implemented natively in C, and has no Python source to show.

Since CPython is open-source, you can poke around and find the C source yourself. For `property`, it's declared here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58f5227d7cdff803609a0bda6882997b3a5ec4bf/Objects/descrobject.c#L1958-L2000

You can look at the referenced symbols to see the details, e.g. `property_methods` is the list of this class' methods, defined here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58f5227d7cdff803609a0bda6882997b3a5ec4bf/Objects/descrobject.c#L1575-L1581