# Get string representation of a function in python

Tags: python

I've seen this question:

[How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

But I can't find anything that works generically for built-in functions and user-defined functions.

eg, I try:

```
>>> print.__repr__()
'<built-in function print>'
```

and

```
>>> repr(print)
'<built-in function print>'
```

and

```
>>> print(print)
<built-in function print>
```

and

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
>>> inspect.getsource(print)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 968, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 768, in findsource
    file = getsourcefile(object)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 684, in getsourcefile
    filename = getfile(object)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 666, in getfile
    'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
TypeError: <built-in function print> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

How can I do this?

### Update:

Duplication police: this isn't a duplicate.  I'm obviously literally citing and acknowledging the question this is allegedly a duplicate of in the very first line of this question and asking for something expanding on that.

Comment: you can use `inspect` for python function signature https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature

Comment: Built-in functions weren't written in python though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Comment: There is no way to get the source of built-in functions implemented in C, since their source code is not present in the Python distribution, nor is there an index to C source code locations for the function. You need to inspect the cpython repository and find the function yourself.

Comment: Thank.  @Amadan are there any tools that do this operation automatically?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, unless someone goes and writes such a mapping. And I don't believe anyone has.

Comment: By the way, here's [`print` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62be74290aca26d16f3f55ece7ff6dad14e60e8d/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1816) that you wanted.

Comment: [This link](https://devguide.python.org/exploring/) found in the dupe is awesome for digging through CPython sources.

Comment: Oh neat, the AST documentation alone is worth it.  Thanks!  Sorry I didn't see the original when I posted this, I can normally count on google-fu and stackoverflow's similar questions to surface it, but didn't see with my query.