# How to know the hidden codes for functions and methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

What are the codes written behind the Python built-in functions and methods? If I want to know them like `sort()` `len()` etc., what do I want to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Comment: see https://github.com/python/cpython