# How can I find the builtin function code?

Tags: python, built-in

I just want to take a look builtin function code. Because I'm a beginner on Python and I think some source code can give me very useful instruction. I made some test code as follows and I did 'Ctrl+click' on 'join' with PyCharm IDE.

```
zip_command = "zip -r {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

And then cursor points `builtin.py` module's join function, but there is empty code. There is only an explanation. How does this operate? Where is the real code?

```
def join(self, ab=None, pq=None, rs=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    Concatenate any number of strings.

    The string whose method is called is inserted in between each given string.
    The result is returned as a new string.

    Example: '.'.join(['ab', 'pq', 'rs']) -> 'ab.pq.rs'
    """
    pass
```

'builtin.py' path is : C:\Users\admin.PyCharmCE2019.3\system\python_stubs\542861396\builtins.py

Comment: PyCharm is lying to you. `builtins.py` is not a real Python source file; it's something that PyCharm made up. I don't know why they thought this was a good idea.

Comment: If you're a Python beginner, reading the source code of built-in functions is likely to be more confusing than useful, because all that stuff is actually written in C.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That should be the accepted answer. Most of the python source is in C.

Comment: It might be useful in illustrating a few things and generating appreciation for how programming languages work. Even though I don't know much, I still feel like I learn a bit via osmosis when glancing at Python source, like "oh hey, that sort of makes sense..." etc. Looking under the hood every now and then is good for the soul.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim More generally, the type `str` and its methods are built into the Python implementation; the reference and most commonly used version is written in C, but other implementations have existed and can exist, not all of them written in C.

Comment: @chepner That's true I forgot about Jython, Iron Python, and others like that. I assumed he was talking about the standard official python.

Answer (score 1):

`str.join()` is implemented in C, specifically in [unicodeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c) at [`unicode_join`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bace59d8b8e38f5c779ff6296ebdc0527f6db14a/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12364).

"How can I find the source code for builtin functions and objects" doesn't have a great answer.  See [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8608587/7954504) for some overviews of how CPython is laid out.  While some of Python's standard library is written in Python (this sits in [lib/](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib)), you'll find that builtins and some performance-sensitive components of the standard library have a C implementation.  The former resides in [objects/](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects), and the latter in [modules/](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules).