# How to find source code of python inner function like list.index()?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check the source code of `list.index()` function to calculate the time complexity. I know that Some inner functions in python are written in `C/C++`. 
Where can I find the source code like this?

Comment: this ? [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2509