# how to get C++/Python source code of a Python Obj?

Tags: python, c++

Python int obj has dynamic memory allocation. When the number is small, memory is small; when large, otherwise. But the numpy array unit has fixed memory once declared.

I am very curious about how python implemented these mechanisms in its source code, either in C++ or Python code.

Where can I get a valid version of python source code to have a look? And, how to find the answer to a question, like above?

Comment: If you make a NumPy array from data - there's no issue to allocate a buffer big enough to fit the data. When you try to expand the array and it doesn't fit the buffer - just allocate a buffer that is bigger than previous. What's curious in that?

Comment: Have you tried a common search engine? The one I'm using, when fed with the words "source code of python", returns https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ which looks pretty authoritative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Comment: @Hans the source code looks good but I can not locate where the class 'int' is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPython source is available via [github.com/python](https://github.com/python/), for discussion of implementation (rather than code only) see [laurentluce.com post](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/).